# Unable to add external libraries to IDEA Tomcat runconfig's runtime classpath

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2. Maven project, single module, war packaging. I have set up a Tomcat Server run configuration for local testing.

The project has an external, properietary dependency (let's call it X), which has platform-dependent variants, so I have to use a different jar for Windows and Linux platforms. The X-win.jar is accompanied by a bunch of dll files, while the X-linux.jar is accompanied by a bunch of *.so files.

Since none of these are available via online Maven repositories, I had to set up a local repository and upload various versions of library X to it. I upload separate versions for Windows and Linux platform manually after getting the files from the vendor of X. There's a separate artifact for X.jar and an X-resources.tar.gz, which contains all the native library files that X.jar is supposed to use.

What I figured out so far:

1. Add the X.jar dependency with scope=provided because it is sufficient to have the Java classes at compile time. The version is different depending on the platform used - Maven profiles and activation are used to decide between win-X.Y.Z and linux-X.Y.Z versions.
2. When I put the war file on an actual server, in an actual Tomcat instance, I should add the platform specific X.jar + dll/so files to Tomcat's libraries and via that to the runtime classpath. This can be done either:

- by putting all the files into $CATALINA_BASE/lib/ or
- by putting them on a path which is then inserted into PATH (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Linux) environment variable and then passed to Tomcat.

What I couldn't figure out is how I do this latter part (adding the platform-dependent jar + native libraries to the runtime classpath via Tomcat) in IDEA. What I tried:

- Passing a -Djava.library.path VM option via Tomcat Server run configuration.
- Adding X.jar and the dir with the dlls (Native Library Locations) to the Application Server Libraries section. Not very elegant because Tomcat settings are not project-specific - they will be used in other IDEA projects' runconfigs, too.
- Adding X.jar and the dir with the dlls (Native Library Locations) to Project Structure | Project Settings | Libraries and also to Project Structure | Project Settings | Modules | Dependencies. The latter gets erased after every Maven Project Import action, which may explain why this method did not work.

Neither of the above worked. The webapp context initialization consistently throws ClassNotFound errors for a class in X.

Comment: The situation is simpler than you think. The jars go where any other jar would go - into WEB-INF/lib. All you've got to decide is where to put the native binaries and then to ensure that the library path is given in your runtime options

Comment: If it is similar to eclipse, by default the tomcat is "cloned" to a kind of temp folder. So your jars should be in that folder.  Are you using windows?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, IDEA runs on Windows. I'm not familiar with how Tomcat launch configurations work in Eclipse, feel free to elaborate.